# Applying class style from component style

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a global style file called `styles.scss` and style for component `detail.scss`.

The global style file called `styles.scss` has the following class:

```
.one .two a{
     color: green
}
```

The style for component `detail.scss` also has style:

```
.fooColor { 
     color: orange
} 

#idColor {  
     color: yellow
}
```

However, the global style is applied to `<a/>` element:

```
<a class="fooColor">Hello, world!:)</a> <!-- Not OK. The color is green, but should
    be orange -->
```

If I set `id`, then the color is okay:

```
<a id="idColor">Hello, world!:)</a> <!--OK. the color is yellow -->
```

This is how I include component style:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    templateUrl: 'foo.html',
    styleUrls: ['detail.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated, //also tried without 
        //"encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated" and "ViewEncapsulation.None"
    moduleId: module.id
})
```

What can I do to apply class `.fooColor` from component style?

Comment: it's called "specificity": `.two a` is more specific than `.fooColor`, but `#fooColor` is way more specific than `.two a` (of course unless you use `!important`): https://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: Try `a.fooColor { ... }`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I've tried to write this `a.fooColor`, however the color is not desirable.

Comment: in detail.scss, try  `.one .two a.fooColor` {...} instead of just `.fooColor`. Your local style should be more specific than your general style.

Comment: Are the elements with classes `one` and `two` inside of your component?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yeah, elements are inside of component

Comment: @roroxide thanks, I’ll try it tomorrow.

Comment: @ConnorsFan please, write you suggestion and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: My suggestion or @roroxide's suggestion? Which solution worked?

Comment: @ConnorsFan your suggestion has worked for me. I wrote incorrect class name in your suggestion. I upvoted other answers of @ roroxide. Thanks for your effort, @ roroxide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the anchor tag to make the selector more specific and override the global style:

```
a.fooColor { 
    color: orange;
}
```

Adding the component tag is another way to make the selector more specific:

```
foo a.fooColor { 
    color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.fooColor.fooColor {
    color: orange;
 }
```

This will increase class specificity over an attribute selection.